# Wordpress Archive drop down yearly

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I have a yearly archive drop-down select box on wordpress. Here is the code:

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Year' ) ); ?></option> 
<?php wp_get_archives( 'type=yearly&format=option&show_post_count=0' ); ?>
</select>
```

Once I select a year, say 2006, the drop down box should display 2006. At present it shows the default "Select Year".

Comment: I don't understand what the question is? You mean you want to preselect a year when the page loads anew?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the [wp_get_archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) function has no ability to set a "default" selected year.

As such you have a few alternatives:

1. Implement your own function based on wp_get_archives. It's quite a deep function and may change in future implementations, so this probably isn't a good idea.
2. Post process the data returned from wp_get_archives to add in a ' selected="selected"' for the current year.
3. Use a JavaScript function that executes when the page is loaded to scan the select options and set the default.

Of these, I'd probably go with the second option. (You should simply be able to do a str_replace based on finding the required `<option value='XXX'>` and swapping it with `<option value='XXX' selected="selected">`.)

Comment: I would be happy to go with #2 but could you send the full code here as I'm not sure how to put that snippet in.

Comment: @Barnabas Nagy - Sorry, I don't have a Wordpress install handy to code it on. However, the wp_get_archives function can be set (using the echo parameter set to false - see the docs I linked to above) to return rather than outputting. As such, you simply need to capture the returned data in a variable and then str_replace to data in the variable as I outlined above prior to outputting it.